# C#, dynamic linq error No applicable method 'Contains' exists in type 'String'

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic-linq

I have a list of objects like this (I am using .NET 3.5)

```
public class MyObjects
{
    public object Name { get; set; }
    public bool Case { get; set; }
}

List<MyObjects> test = new List<MyObjects> { 

    new MyObjects { Name = "one" },
    new MyObjects { Name = "two" },
    new MyObjects { Name = "three" },
    new MyObjects { Name = "four" },
    new MyObjects { Name = "one1" },
    new MyObjects { Name = "two1" },
    new MyObjects { Name = "three1" },
    new MyObjects { Name = "four1" },
    new MyObjects { Name = "one2" },
    new MyObjects { Name = "two2" },
    new MyObjects { Name = "three2" },
    new MyObjects { Name = "four2" },
};
```

Now I try to search in the list using Linq.
This is working as expected

```
var tmp = test
    .Select(p => p.Name)
    .Where(x => x.ToString().Contains("One", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
    ;
```

Using Dynamic Linq, this also works as expected

```
var dtmp = test.AsQueryable()
    .Select(p => p.Name)
    .Where("ToString().Contains(@0)", "one")
    ;
```

However, when trying to use case (in)sensitive, the dynamic fails.

```
var dtmp2 = test.AsQueryable()
    .Select(p => p.Name)
    .Where("ToString().Contains(@0, @1)", "one", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
    ;
```

The error is

```
No applicable method 'Contains' exists in type 'String'
```

My first attempt was to write a Contains() extension like this

```
public static bool Contains(this string source, string toCheck, StringComparison comp)
{
    return source.IndexOf(toCheck, comp) >= 0;
}
```

Appears that Dynamic Linq isn't aware of my extension. I discovered (according to this)
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/39763339-1700-486f-9800-badd257e921e/custom-extension-methods-and-dynamic-linq-dynamic-expression-api?forum=linqprojectgeneral

that Dynamic Linq cannot uses (static) extension very easily.

So either:

1. Transform extension in a normal method. However, how can I do this for every ToString(), is it possible or should I write a method in MyObject then use linq with specific objects ?
2. Modify the Dynamic Library code to accept hard coded (my)static extensions.
3. Other suggestions?

Note: I could use a simple if/else for case sensitive with two dynamics but I prefer to solve the dynamic way since my app use some complex filtering.

Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 1):

If your application needs dynamic filter capabilities, I would recommend having the caller pass a predicate.

This allows for a separation of concerns and easier unit testing.

Also, no need for a IF/ELSE statement when the caller passes a predicate.

```
var predicate = new Predicate<string>(str => str.Contains("one"));

var tmp = test.Select(p => p.Name).Where(predicate);
```

Comment: Hmm.. I see. Plus PredicateBuilder. But still I have to use IF/ELSE for case sensitive options.

Comment: @orfruit The predicate can use your `Contains` extension method with the `StringComparision`. The caller is responsible for creating the predicate which returns the correct results. IMO without reviewing your code, there should not be a need for the IF/ELSE.

Comment: I am investigating now (actually abandoned) predicate solution. I have a Search form that have a combo with (StartsWith, EndsWith, Equals and Contains) and a checkbox for case sensitive. Thanks for support!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using [System.Linq.Dynamic.Core](https://github.com/StefH/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core) because it seems that this library can handle your example c# code.